# Calculations based on JTextFields

Tags: java, swing

I am looking to take all data from the `JTextField`'s and add them together then output the answer to a text file.

```
    static class Session implements ActionListener {
                public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
    JButton submitInvoice = new JButton ("Submit");
                    sPanel.add(submitInvoice);
                    submitInvoice.addActionListener(e8->{
                        try{
                            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("RegInvoice.txt"));
                                bw.write("---------------Booking Invoice---------------");
                                bw.write("\r\n");
                                bw.write("All Day: "); bw.write(tSesh1.getText());
                                bw.write("\r\n");
                                bw.write("Morning: "); bw.write(tSesh2.getText());
                                bw.write("\r\n");
                                bw.write("Lunch: "); bw.write(tSesh3.getText());
                                bw.write("\r\n");
                                bw.write("Afternoon: "); bw.write(tSesh4.getText());
                                bw.write("\r\n");
                                bw.write("Pre School: "); bw.write(tSesh5.getText());
                                bw.write("\r\n");
                                bw.write("Full Holiday Care: "); bw.write(tSesh6.getText());
                                bw.close();
                        }catch(Exception ex){
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
             }
   }
```

The above code takes the tSesh1,tSesh2, tSesh3, tSesh4, tSesh5 and prints them to a file. But I need to add each `JTextField` together.

Comment: What do you mean by "add each JTextField together"? Give an example of the content of each box and the result you are trying to get.

Comment: JTextField contains a number. The numbers are put in by the user. So in JTextField 1 the number is 5, and in JTextField the number is 1. I want these two numbers to be added together for a total of 6

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(tSesh1.getText()) + Integer.parseInt(tSesh2.getText())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the integer value of each field by parsing the String returned by TEXTFIELD.getText()

```
int field1 = Integer.parseInt(TEXTFIELD1.getText());
int field2 = Integer.parseInt(TEXTFIELD2.getText());
```

You can do this with as many jTextFields as you need. Then you can use the integers to do any calculations necessary.

i.e.

```
int total = field1 + field2;
```

Comment: After that how do I print the total to a text file? @Rob Rushton

Comment: *"After that.."* ..ask a new question (on a new question thread).